# Java stream to sort list by some value, and then sort duplicates by another value

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

Let's say that I have simple Worker class:

```
    public class Worker {

        private String name;
        private Date birthDate;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Date getBirthDate() {
            return birthDate;
        }

        public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }
}
```

And I have a list with some workers, and I need to apply following sorting for this list:

1) Sort workers by birthDate

2) If there are workers with duplicate birth dates, then I need to sort those workers by name

For example:

> Adam 02/11/1995
>
> Kane 11/05/1986
>
> Mike 17/09/1999
>
> Ben 17/09/1999
>
> Robert 17/09/1999

Order after sorting by birthDate:

> Kane 11/05/1986
>
> Adam 02/11/1995
>
> Mike 17/09/1999
>
> Ben 17/09/1999
>
> Robert 17/09/1999

Order after sorting date duplicates by name:

> Kane 11/05/1986
>
> Adam 02/11/1995
>
> Ben 17/09/1999
>
> Mike 17/09/1999
>
> Robert 17/09/1999

So, on second step I need to save order of workers as it is after first step, and only change it for workers with duplicate birth dates

Is there some simple way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Worker> workers;
...
List<Workers> sorted =
  workers.stream()
    .sorted(
      Comparator.comparing(Worker::getBirthDate)
        .thenComparing(Worker::getName))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: pholser, thank you, turns out it is really simple to do with streams )

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Worker {

    private String name;
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public Worker(String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Worker [name=" + name + ", birthDate=" + birthDate + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker w1 = new Worker("Adam", LocalDate.of(1995, 11, 02));
        Worker w2 = new Worker("Kane", LocalDate.of(1986, 5, 11));
        Worker w3 = new Worker("Mike", LocalDate.of(1999, 9, 17));
        Worker w4 = new Worker("Ben", LocalDate.of(1999, 9, 17));
        Worker w5 = new Worker("Robert", LocalDate.of(1999, 9, 17));

        List<Worker> list = Arrays.asList(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5);
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Worker::getBirthDate).thenComparing(Worker::getName));

        for (Worker w : list) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Worker [name=Kane, birthDate=1986-05-11]
Worker [name=Adam, birthDate=1995-11-02]
Worker [name=Ben, birthDate=1999-09-17]
Worker [name=Mike, birthDate=1999-09-17]
Worker [name=Robert, birthDate=1999-09-17]
```

I also recommend you use modern Date API e.g. `LocalDate` instead of `Date`. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for more details.